# LINQ to filter by entity FieldName.Contains OR by included entity FieldName.Contains

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables: `TradeItem` and `BarCode`. Latter stores BarCodes for TradeItems. TradeItem can have any (or none) number of BarCodes.

```
[Table("BarCode")]
public partial class BarCode
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PK { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid FK_TradeItem { get; set; }
    public virtual TradeItem TradeItem { get; set; }
}

[Table("TradeItem")]
public partial class TradeItem
{
    public TradeItem()
    {
        BarCodes = new HashSet<BarCode>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid PK { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BarCode> BarCodes { get; set; }
}

public partial class SOModel : DbContext
{
    public SOModel(): base("name=SOContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<BarCode> BarCodes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TradeItem> TradeItems { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TradeItem>()
            .HasMany(e => e.BarCodes)
            .WithRequired(e => e.TradeItem)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.FK_TradeItem)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Using `EntityFramework`, I want to have a LINQ expression that would return TradeItems if `TradeItem.Name` OR `TradeItem.Description` OR related `BarCode.Name` contain some string, like '123'.
Can do a LINQ expression to filter by `TradeItem.Name` OR `TradeItem.Description`.
Can do a LINQ expression to filter by included `BarCode.Name`.
But I can't combine those two expressions.
I know that SQL Server's VIEW can be used for that, but I want to have an entity of type `TradeItem`, with included entity of type BarCode.
Can anyone help me with that LINQ please?

Comment: Please show C# / LINQ details, not SQL.

Comment: @NetMage edited, please reopen my question

Comment: I voted to reopen, I can't reopen by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
public class AppDbContext: DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(): base("DefaultConnection")
    {   }
    public DbSet<TradeItem> TradeItems { get; set; }
}

public class TradeItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Decription { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BarCode> BarCodes { get; } = new List<BarCode>();
}

public class BarCode
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new AppDbContext() )
        {
            string test="123";

        var tradeItems =
            ctx.TradeItems
                .Where((ti) => ti.Name.Contains(test) || ti.Decription.Contains(test) || ti.BarCodes.Any((bc) => bc.Name.Contains(test)))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var ti in tradeItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ti.Id} : {ti.Name} : {ti.Decription}");
            foreach (var bc in ti.BarCodes)
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{bc.Id} : {bc.Name}");
        }
    }
}
}
```